# String to list python conversion

Tags: python, string, list

My input string looks like below

```
rule = "['xor',[{'asset':'pc','operator':'=','basis':true}]]"
```

Expected output

```
 Output = ['xor',[{'asset':'pc','operator':'=','basis':true}]]
```

Also this is legacy code  where I cannot do `ast.literal_eval(rule)` since basis has non-string value `true` which will throw error 'malformed string'

Any suggestions to do the same?

I tried with `rule.strip('][').split(', ')`, but the output is not the expected format:

```
["'and',[{'fact':'waived','operator':'=','basis':true}"]
```

Comment: What is `true` supposed to be?

Comment: Is this thing supposed to be some kind of wrongly-quoted JSON?

Comment: The true should ideally be a json but not be in legacy code ,have to handle that condition in the code

Comment: true should ideally have been passed as 'true' from UI to backend - which is not ought to be in legacy code

Comment: true is defined in JavaScript while it is True in Python hence the mismatch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're OK with using eval, then you can define `true` in the environment to eval:

```
>>> rule = "['xor',[{'asset':'pc','operator':'=','basis':true}]]"
>>> print(eval(rule, {'true': True}))
['xor', [{'basis': True, 'asset': 'pc', 'operator': '='}]]
```

Comment: I believe OP should accept this as the answer. I infact learned something new here today. That's a nice thing to share @thebjorn

Comment: @thebjron if the input is changed to  ['xor',[{'asset':'pc','operator':'=','basis':true}]] I cant run eval on it . anyways to overcome that

Comment: It's early Sunday morning here, but I don't see what the change is? If you mean that the ordering of keys in the dict is different, then you just need to upgrade to a Python version that preserves dict-key order (don't remember when that was changed off the top of my head...)

Answer (score 1):

I think if you are not using tuples in those strings you could parse it as json.

```
import json
my_data = json.loads(my_string)
```

This will depend on the details of what you parsing though so buyer beware.

Comment: That seems like something that can pretty easily be corrected with replace()

Comment: yep, `rule.replace("'", '"')`

Comment: @gph no actually, in general, it can't. But it may suffice for the OP's purposes

Comment: which is why I said the solution will depend on the details.